# Заменить протокол открытой вкладки

Tags: http, https, chrome-extension, протоколы

Всем привет, хочу сделать расширение chrome которое при клике на его значок в панели расшерений (или дополнительной кнопке) будет менять протокол http:// на asas://. Но как это сделать я вообще не знаю, и не гуглится что-то ничего, я просто создаю расширение-болванку. Если вы сможете написать часть кода или ссылки на документации/инструкции буду очень признателен. Спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: https://github.com/jeffersonking/chrome-cors/blob/master/background.js посмотри пример

Comment: но ещё проблема кто будет обработчиком asas